# user cannot execute procedure that tuncates a table

Tags: mysql

I have created a procedure to truncate a table supplied in a parameter..

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`imerrywe`@`%` PROCEDURE `truncate_table`(`table` 
    VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN

        SET @s = CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', @table);
        PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
    END
```

The procedure works fine when I call it when I'm logged in as  'imerrywe'...

mysql> call truncate_table('test_table');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

I created a test user and granted the user execute permission on the procedure but when I try to call the procedure when logged in as that user it won't execute...

mysql> call truncate_table('test_table');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Is there some missing permission ?

Comment: Remember that a routine parameter is distinct from a [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). Try: `SET @s = CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', \`table\`);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@table is a variable Please Use this one :-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`imerrywe`@`%` PROCEDURE `truncate_table`(in_table 
VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    SET @s = CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', in_table);
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
END
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly now.